# Distance between two lines

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

> Find the distance between the lines $l_1:$ $x=1+4t,y=5-4t,z=-1+5t$ and $l_2:x=2+8t,y=4-3t,z=5+t$

So the approach in general is to find a vector that is orthogonal to 2 planes that the lines are in them.

I saw that the cross product is used to find this vector as in the following:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k}  \\ 
4 & -4 & 5 \\ 
8 & -3 & 1  \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=11\hat{i}+36\hat{j}+20\hat{k}$$

How can the cross product be used here? why does it give a vector that is  orthogonal to 2 planes?

Comment: "find a vector that is orthogonal to 2 planes": no this doesn't make sense unless the planes are parallel to each other. You need to find a vector that is orthogonal to the two *lines*.

Comment: Yes, they are parallel sorry for the bad description

Answer (score 1):

Because a line joining a point from one of the lines to a second point from the other line will be the shortest when it is perpendicular to both lines. Perpendicular to a line, means perpendicular to its generating vector, i.e. coefficients of its equation. And in three dimension all vectors that are simultaneously perpendicular to two vectors are multiples of their cross-product (when those vectors are not parallel.)

Comment: But I would parameterize the lines, one with $s \in R$ the other with $t$. Then minimize a 2nd order polynomial in two variables. Very easy.